# Scroll menu in html css

Tags: html, css

This is the current code I have, but instead of becoming a scroll menu at a certain size, it is just making the page longer. The link is posted over and over many times to make sure it fills the page and more, I just didn't paste those divs in here for clarity/length.

```
<div class="column1" style="float: left; text-align: left; overflow:scroll; height:20px">
  <div>
    <h5>
      <a href="#4_May_2023"> 4 May 2023 </a>
    </h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

`column1` just sets the spacing on the page, for reference. I used overflow:scroll and set a fixed height at `20px` to make it shorter than the page to force a scroll, but it just continues to be very long.

Comment: Do you have a _good reason_ for using `float:` instead of other, modern and more _flex_-ible techniques?

Comment: Also, what does "scroll menu" mean, exactly?

Comment: I used float because I'm pretty new to coding html/css so I wanted to be able to do it that way before trying to use flex to make my page. By scroll menu, I meant that I wanted to split my page into a menu on one side with clickable links to different areas of the same page to skip around, as the other side of the page is going to be different sections. Currently, the other side is shorter than the scroll menu since I wanted to test out trying to make the menu scrollable. I am using <nav> at the top of the page, so I made the columns underneath and making them the menu/content for this tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can add menu after the main address

```html
<div class="column1" style="float: left; text-align: left; overflow:scroll; max-height: 200px;">
  <div>
    <h5>
      <a href="#4_May_2023"> 4 May 2023 </a>
    </h5>
    <!-- add more links here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

.column1 must have a property

```
{width: 100%}
```

to have size of the container it is placed in. Otherwise, its width is defined by its content, that has bigger size.